# IntelliJ "The SDK is not specified for modules .."

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, sdk

My org uses custom IntelliJ plugins through which we perform 'sync' from remote. Recently I ran into troubles with few symbols not being recognized after my change because of either code auto-generation (from XML schemas) not working correctly or the IDE resolving a wrong classpath for auto-generated code.

That's when I tried a bunch of fixes including deleting `.idea/` directory and un-installing / re-installing our custom plugins. After that when I'm trying to perform a sync, it fails with following error

```
The SDK is not specified for modules {module_1}, {module_2} ..
```

[image: screenshot-1: main error]

---

To clarify

1. `Project Settings` > (Project) `SDK` is defined and most of the symbols are getting recognized
2. Even under `Project Settings` > `Modules` > `Dependencies`, `Module SDK` is defined for all modules. But for half of those it is still showing as `<No SDK>` in that list of dependencies (see 3rd screenshot below)

   - and when I right click on those `<No SDK>` list items, in the popup the options to `Edit`, `Remove` etc are all greyed out

[image: screenshot-2: Project SDK is defined]

[image: screenshot-3: For half the modules, Module SDK is also properly defined]

[image: screenshot-4: For other half modules, Module SDK is not defined properly and options to edit that are greyed out]

At the same time I'm getting some strange red-wavy line errors like

```
Required type: String
Provided: java.lang.String
```

[image: screenshot-5: I'm getting some strange errors]

---

I've tried

- restarting IDE multiple times
- upgrade to latest IDE version, downgraded to penultimate version
- (already mentioned above) removing `.idea/` directory
- (already mentioned above) un-installing + re-installing custom plugins

What else could I try?

---

I'm on

- IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5 (Ultimate Edition)
  Build #IU-232.10227.8, built on November 9, 2023

  - I have also tried v2023.3 but some plugins were incompatible so had to downgrade
- macBook Pro with Apple M1 Prod running macOS Ventura 13.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Looks related to this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-330994 (Project SDK is not applied to submodules and can't edit SDK if the "org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle" is in disabled_plugins.txt)

Try to find [<IDE_Setting_Folder>](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory)/disabled_plugins.txt and remove the `org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle` in that file, restart the IDE to see if it helps.